# Logica para ordenação de um array B de inteiros com base em um array A de char

Tags: c, array, classificação

Estou tentando desenvolver um algoritmo para um projeto meu, mas me deparei com a dificuldade que é ordenar os indices em um array B de outro array A. Meu código no atual momento nem compila, gostaria de uma ajuda no desenvolvimento da lógica.
ps: sou iniciante, perdão qualquer gafe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int indices[5],i,j;
    char nomes[5][255] = {"Pedro","John","Gabriel","Taissa","Adolfo"};

    for( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i)
    {
        for( j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            if(strcmp(nomes[j], nomes[j+1]) > 0)
            {
                indices[j] = j+1; 
                indices[j+1]= j;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nValores ORDENADOS \n");
    
    for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s",nomes[indices[i]]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

*Meu objetivo é que o output fosse : `Adolfo,Gabriel,John,Pedro,Taissa`*

Answer (score 4):

Não precisa criar cópias das strings (como foi sugerido em outras respostas). Se a ideia é ordenar apenas os índices, então o array de strings não precisa ser alterado.

Primeiro você precisa inicializar o array de índices:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    indices[i] = i;
}
```

Depois, você usa os elementos deste array como índices das strings sendo comparadas. Ou seja, em vez de `nomes[j]`, deve-se usar `nomes[indices[j]]` (já que você estará comparando a string cujo índice é o valor que está na posição `j` do array de índices).

E para trocar o valor de uma posição com outra, precisa de uma variável auxiliar. Ou seja, se você faz isso:

```c
a = b;
b = a;
```

Na primeira linha `a` recebe o valor de `b`. Depois, na segunda linha, `b` recebe o valor de `a` (que foi setado como `b` na linha anterior). Ou seja, no final ambos terão o valor de `b`. O correto é ter uma variável auxiliar para guardar o valor original de `a`, para que ele não se perca:

```c
tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

---

Portanto, ficaria assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int indices[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        indices[i] = i;
    }
    char nomes[5][255] = {"Pedro", "John", "Gabriel", "Taissa", "Adolfo"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4 - i; j++) {
            if (strcmp(nomes[indices[j]], nomes[indices[j + 1]]) > 0) {
                int tmp = indices[j];
                indices[j] = indices[j + 1];
                indices[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nValores ORDENADOS \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%s%s", nomes[indices[i]], i < 4 ? ",": "");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Valores ORDENADOS 
Adolfo,Gabriel,John,Pedro,Taissa
```

---

Vale lembrar que é possível usar a função `qsort`, em vez de implementar seu próprio algoritmo de ordenação (basta implementar uma função que compare os nomes correspondentes aos índices):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char nomes[5][255] = {"Pedro", "John", "Gabriel", "Taissa", "Adolfo"};

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    // função recebe os índices, e compara os respectivos nomes
    int i = *(int *) a;
    int j = *(int *) b;
    return strcmp(nomes[i], nomes[j]);
}

int main() {
    int indices[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        indices[i] = i;
    }

    qsort(indices, 5, sizeof(int), compare);

    printf("\nValores ORDENADOS \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%s%s", nomes[indices[i]], i < 4 ? "," : "");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Então também não sou nenhum especialista em programação não, pensei em uma solução aqui, acredito que não implementei da melhor maneira possivel, mais foi oque consegui pensar a principio.

Vale ressaltar que você estava utilizando funções da biblioteca string.h sem fazer o include dela no programa por isso não estava conseguindo compilar.

Pensei em fazer um swap (troca de elementos) e armazenar em um vetor auxiliar essa informação, acredito que seja possivel copiar novamente para o vetor original, mais deixei no auxiliar mesmo, ai verificando o que precisávamos como saída identifiquei que 3 trocas seriam o suficiente, como ilustrei na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se trata de um array de string podemos passar um ponteiro para o ponteiro que aponta para o conteúdo do array, como argumento para a função como segue:

```
void swap(char **a, char **b) {
    char *temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Após isso foi só fazer as trocas e armazenar no vetor auxiliar

```
int main() {
    int i, j;
    char *nomes[5] = {"Pedro","John","Gabriel","Taissa","Adolfo"};
    char *aux[5];
    int n = sizeof(nomes)/sizeof(*nomes);

    swap(&nomes[3], &nomes[4]);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        aux[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(nomes[i])+1));
        strcpy(aux[i], nomes[i]);
    }
    printf("swap(3,4)\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("[%s]",aux[i]);
    }

    swap(&aux[0], &aux[3]);
    printf("\nswap(0,4)\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("[%s]",aux[i]);
    }

    //outro swap com array auxiliar
    swap(&aux[1], &aux[2]);
    printf("\nswap(1,2)\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("[%s]",aux[i]);
    }


    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(aux[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Eu acredito que provavelmente essa não é a forma mais **eficiente** ou até mesmo correta de fazer esse exercício, já que tem que indicar de forma estática cada troca, se houverem mais respostas gostaria de aprender também formas mais elegantes e eficientes de resolver o mesmo problema, caso fique alguma dúvida, se eu souber responder terei o maior prazer, caso contrario descobrimos uma resposta.

segue o cod completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char **a, char **b) {
    char *temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}


int main() {
    int i, j;
    char *nomes[5] = {"Pedro","John","Gabriel","Taissa","Adolfo"};
    char *aux[5];
    int n = sizeof(nomes)/sizeof(*nomes);

    swap(&nomes[3], &nomes[4]);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        aux[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(nomes[i])+1));
        strcpy(aux[i], nomes[i]);
    }
    printf("swap(3,4)\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("[%s]",aux[i]);
    }

    swap(&aux[0], &aux[3]);
    printf("\nswap(0,4)\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("[%s]",aux[i]);
    }

    //outro swap com array auxiliar
    swap(&aux[1], &aux[2]);
    printf("\nswap(1,2)\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("[%s]",aux[i]);
    }


    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(aux[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui desenvolver uma lógica que serve para uma quantia MAX de valores dentro do vetor e sem necessariamente estar olhando para o vetor.

Esse é o Codigo :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 4

int main ()
{
  char nomes[MAX][255] = {"Pedro","Zebra","Abrao","Arnoldo"},aux[255];
  char vetor_aux[MAX][255];
  int i, j, n ,vetor_indice[MAX];

  // FAZENDO UMA COPIA DO VETOR ORIGINAL
  for (i = 0 ; i < MAX ; ++i)
    {
      strcpy(vetor_aux[i],nomes[i]);
    }
  
  // IMPRIMINDO COPIA
  printf("\n Vetor desordenado ! \n");
  for( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; ++i)
  {
    printf("%s e seu indice eh : %d \n",vetor_aux[i], i);    
  }

  // ORDENANDO OS CHAR'S PARA PEGAR SEUS INDICES
  for( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; ++i ) // 4 é X 
  {
    for ( j = 0 ; j < (MAX - i - 1) ; ++j) // ficaria X (J < X - i - 1 ) // i é o contador 
    {
      if(strcmp(vetor_aux[j], vetor_aux[j+1]) > 0) // 
        {
          strcpy(aux,vetor_aux[j]);
          strcpy(vetor_aux[j],vetor_aux[j+1]);
          strcpy(vetor_aux[j+1],aux);
        }
    } 
  }

  // PEGANDO O INDICE POR MEIO DE UMA COMPARAÇÃO 
  for( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; ++i )
  {
      for ( j = 0 ; j < MAX ; ++j)
      {
          if( (!strcmp(nomes[j], vetor_aux[i]))) // copia dos nomes 
          {
                vetor_indice[i] = j;
          }
      } 
  }
  
  
  printf("\nVetor ordenado\n");
  for( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; ++i)
  {
    printf("%s\n", nomes[ vetor_indice[i] ] );    
  }

  
  printf("\n Os indices são ::\n");
  for( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; ++i)
  {
    printf("%d e esta vinculado ao %s\n", vetor_indice[i], nomes[vetor_indice[i]] );    
    
  }

  
  return 0;  
}
```

Explicação :

Para julgar um vetor de tamanho n e ordená-lo, na minha lógica, é necessário usar um algoritmo que ordene esse vetor seja ele bubble sort (Foi o que usei), mas sem alterar o vetor original, para isso faço uma copia do mesmo ( vou chamar de VETOR B).
Dado o Vetor B agora é necessário saber para que indice, no vetor original, ele aponta e armazenar em um Vetor de inteiros ( vou chamar de VETOR C ), por meio de um for duplo com uma comparação é simples achá-lo `if( (!strcmp(nomes[j], vetor_aux[i]))) // copia dos nomes` .

E sem delongas, basta imprimir o vetor original com o valor armazenado no vetor C `printf("%s\n", nomes[ vetor_indice[i] ] );`

Espero que esteja claro, é possível implementar melhorias para ficar mais usual( mandar todos para low case é uma boa), mas essa foi a forma que encontrei pra responder essa questão sem necessariamente olhar para o vetor.